# Firebase - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT | FIRApp.configure() | Swift 4

Tags: firebase, swift4, xcode9

[image: Screenshot of Error]

I want to use Firebase, I installed it to my project, but when I write `FIRApp.configure()` in AppDelegate.swift, I'm getting `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. How can I solve this problem? I'm using Swift 4 with Xcode 9.

Comment: Please update your question to include the error. If you look in the debug area in the bottom right of Xcode, scroll up to the beginning of that error and it will give you a description.

Comment: I updated my pods, and I choose target membership; everything is great, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Update cocoapods and re install Podfile.
Change:
FIRApp.configure() -> FirebaseApp.configure()
Also change language settings from Swift 4 -> Swift 3.2

That worked for me.
Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've been pulling my hair for 2 days...

here is what I found

1. make sure you have the right GoogleService-info.plist file
2. enable the .plist file point to your target app

[image]